# How to get alias.table from oracle database using HikariCP

Tags: spring, oracle11g, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I came across this issue most recently. I am not sure if it's from HikariCP or Oracle or Spring Boot. When I try to use schema from datasource.schema(application.yml/application.properties) I am getting an error. HikariCP starts but fails immediatly saying property schema doesn't exist. Now how are we supposed to use schema in oracle databases?

driver class name : oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource - ojdbc-7

> main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Started.
>
> main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf : Property schema does not
>   exist on target class oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

(I know I can't set up schema for HikariCP! But how now?)

Is it at all possible to connect to oracle database using schema(alias) using HikariCP?

For those who are wondering wth is HikariCP:
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP good place to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution!

HikariCP takes ConnectionInitSql property we can set this to:

ConnectionInitSql =alter session set current_schema=xyz(Your Schema Name)

[Solution Page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/617)

```
public DataSource datasource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties){
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
    ds.setUsername(dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
    ds.setConnectionInitSql("alter session set current_schema=My_Schema");
    return new HikariDataSource(ds);
}
```